# Spring Boot Admin Server 2.0 with Spring Boot Version 1.5 not working

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-admin

We have Spring Boot Application (Application 1 , which runs on Spring Boot 1.5 and Java 1.8 , and we are trying to use dependency Spring Boot Admin Client 2.0).
Now we have another application (Application 2 , which is on Spring Boot 2.0 , Java 1.8 and Spring Boot Admin Server 2.0 .) We need to set up communication between both of them. We tried tweaking few things but the client fails to register with server. (Application 1 fails to get register with Application 2). Any help would be appreciated . We cannot upgrade to Spring Boot 2.0 for our spring client (Application 1) but wanted to use new Spring Boot Admin server to display stats.

Comment: If anyone still looking for workaround for this, please have a look at : https://stackoverflow.com/a/53348501/1131967

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spring Admin Server 2.x is compatible with Spring boot 2.x application and not with spring boot 1.x application. The main reason in that from Spring boot 1.x and  2.x the actuator module is significantly changed, starting from security concern to how those endpoint are exposed even in the path. The my advice is use a Spring Boot Admin Server 1.x for Spring Boot 1.x application because.

**Update**

However it is possible force the usage of spring boot admin 2 with legacy Spring boot 1.5 how described on *[Monitoring Spring Boot 1.5.x](https://codecentric.github.io/spring-boot-admin/current/#monitoring-spring-boot-1.5.x)* section of the official spring boot admin documentation

Comment: Are there any docs that can support your answer? As @Владимир Уваров has a link to the official documentation of Spring Boot Admin pointing out that Admin 2.x supports monitoring 1.5.x Boot applications.

Comment: hi you are right it is possible to force the application. I answered in this way before, because when I tried so was a very early version on spring boot 2.0 and I found that it did not worked but accually starting from the release version it work thank you for your observetion

Answer (score 2):

https://codecentric.github.io/spring-boot-admin/current/#monitoring-spring-boot-1.5.x

6. Monitoring Spring Boot 1.5.x
   It is possible to monitor Spring Boot 1.5.x applications with Spring Boot Admin 2.x. The old Spring Boot Admin Client is able to register at a newer server. Since the API has slight changes, you need to set the following property on old clients:

Reconfigure the api path for Spring Boot Admin Client 1.5.x:

**application.yml**
**spring.boot.admin.api-path:** *instances*
As some of the actuator endpoints changed with the Spring Boot 2 release not all options might be available (e.g. /metrics endpoint); for some of the endpoints we provide legacy converters.