# Spring Boot Client Failed to register with Admin

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-admin

I have an Spring Boot Admin server running just fine. Here are the files:

`pom.xml`

```
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <spring-boot-admin.version>2.1.0</spring-boot-admin.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>de.codecentric</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-admin-server</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>de.codecentric</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-admin-server-ui</artifactId>
    </dependency>
      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
          <scope>test</scope>
      </dependency>
</dependencies>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>de.codecentric</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-admin-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-boot-admin.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

`application.properties`

```
server.port = 9090
spring.application.name = adminserver
```

`DemoApplication.java`

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAdminServer
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

This works great. I can navigate to `http://localhost:9090/#/applications` and see the admin server just fine.
[image]

The problem is when I try to register one of my client applications to the server. Here are the details for my client application:

`pom.xml`

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.0.RC1</version>
    <relativePath/>
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-hateoas</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>de.codecentric</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-admin-starter-client</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.7</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

`application.yml`

```
spring:
  profiles: default
  boot:
    admin:
      url: http://localhost:9090
management:
  context-path: /actuator
```

When I start up the client application, I can navigate to `http://localhost:8081/actuator/health` and see all the health info just fine. But I also end up getting these errors in the console:

```
DEBUG --- [   registrationTask1] de.codecentric.boot.admin.client.registration.ApplicationRegistrator                       : Failed to register application as Application [name=ClientApp, managementUrl=http://richard-desktop:8081/actuator/, healthUrl=http://richard-desktop:8081/actuator/health/, serviceUrl=http://richard-desktop:8081/] at spring-boot-admin ([http://localhost:9090/api/applications]): 404 Not Found 
DEBUG --- [   registrationTask1] de.codecentric.boot.admin.client.registration.ApplicationRegistrator                       : Failed to register application as Application [name=ClientApp, managementUrl=http://richard-desktop:8081/actuator/, healthUrl=http://richard-desktop:8081/actuator/health/, serviceUrl=http://richard-desktop:8081/] at spring-boot-admin ([http://localhost:9090/api/applications]): 404 Not Found 
DEBUG --- [   registrationTask1] de.codecentric.boot.admin.client.registration.ApplicationRegistrator                       : Failed to register application as Application [name=ClientApp, managementUrl=http://richard-desktop:8081/actuator/, healthUrl=http://richard-desktop:8081/actuator/health/, serviceUrl=http://richard-desktop:8081/] at spring-boot-admin ([http://localhost:9090/api/applications]): 404 Not Found
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basically it failing to register because of difference in version of Spring Boot Admin Server(2.1.0) and Client(1.5.7).

Client 1.5.7 hits at server with url //server:port/api/applications but server 2.1.0 expected registration at //server:port/instances path so just need to update the client to hit the expected server path.

Just start the server/client in debug logs to get more hint on what url it trying to hit.

**Point to be noted here that We wont be getting all information due version uncompatability for many endpoints. Actuator module completely changed between 1.X and 2.X.**

With above point, below is workaround to get this done with limitations :

**Client Java file :**

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class ClientApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ClientApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

**Client Property file :**

```
server.port=8081
spring.boot.admin.url=http://localhost:8080
spring.boot.admin.api-path=/instances
management.security.enabled=false
```

Its working for me with limitations like not able to see metrics etc. but still handfull of information visible on Admin Server.

Comment: wow that worked! So I just need to downgrade the server version to be able to see more information

Comment: Right if that is feasible for you then more useful. Worth running client and server with same version.